# This device cannot start(Code 10) when installing a new NIC

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

So I've recently bought a new Intellinet Fast Ethernet PCI Network Card, and I can't get it to work. I've tried uninstalling the previous ethernet card drivers and reinstalling the new ones, but it didn't help. I also disabled the onboard LAN card in UEFI.

Any ideas?

I have a ASRock Z68 Pro3-M motherboard.

Comment: Have you tried a different PCI-E slot?

Comment: Unfortunately, it only has 1. You can see from this pic: http://www.asrock.com/mb/photo/Z68%20Pro3-M(m).jpg

Comment: I see two PCI-E slots on your board.  It does not really matter because I looked up the network card and it brought up results for the PCI-E card instead of the PCI card.  **Has this PCI slot ever worked?**  **You have 3 PCI-E slots by the way not 1**

Comment: http://www.intellinet-network.com/en-US/products/200-fast-ethernet-pci-network-card This is the card I am talking about. It cleary says PCI. This slot has previously never been used, so I cant tell you that.

Comment: Are your intel "chipset" drivers all installed for the motherboard itself?

Comment: Yes they are. Would you recommend installing new ones?

Comment: @Kajzer - Yes. I know its a PCI card. My original question asked about PCI-E by mistake and you replied to my incorrect question by saying you only have one slot. I was trying to explain the answer to the question I actually asked was 3. Like I said it does not matter how many PCI-E slots you have because the device you have is a PCI card.  **I am an engineer by trade, I like specifics to be correct, the use of the correct term is important in my trade**

Comment: Sorry for a bit of misscommunication. I will update the drivers now.

Comment: I do not know, I have just seen the chipset group install nic items too, mostly for the onboard chips. They are packing what I would say is too much stuff in there. It was just one idea that popped into my head when seeing your problem. They have ways :-) of highly integrating all this stuff.

Comment: So this silly thing just happened. Removed the card from the slot, put it in another PC, worked fine there, put it back, power up the computer and it worked. Thanks for your help, Psycogeek and Ramhound.

Answer (score 1):

I put the card in another computer, then switched it back and now it's working.

Comment: So is it possible that it was not seated into the slot far enough or properly?  that some aspects of it were connected but not others?  Or an oxidation sluff off (from sliding the connections across more)?

Comment: Could be. Note that the card was recognized in device manager, and the LED was on.